# Facebook response.post_id Composition

Tags: facebook, response, share, userid

I would like to be sure if the first part of the

```
response.post_id
```

that Facebook sends back after a share action ex : 500716428_211026529025294
is always,always the facebook userid  (500716428)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure because the permalink would look like

```
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=211026529025294&id=500716428
```